# Как централизованно вызывать методы и переменные из разных классов?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В игре есть разные объекты, скрипты:
`EquipmentController`, `PlayerAnimator` и пр., штук 10-20, методы и переменные которых используются, то в одном классе, то в другом.
Каждый раз делать связки для каждого класса через `[SerializedField]` и подвязывать ссылки в Inspector немного муторно.

```
[SerializedField] private EquipmentController equipmentController;
// ...
```

Поэтому я сделал Singleton `GameManager` и подвязываю их к нему.
А потом в нужном месте вызываю

```
GameManager.Instance.equipmentController
```

При этом прописываю, чтобы `GameManager` грузился первым.
Меня не покидает ощущение, что это костыль и что-то здесь неправильно... Как делаете вы?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Я думаю, вам стоит обратить внимание на принцип SRP из SOLID. Он ответит на часть вопросов.

Comment: Да, сингтон это костыль. Как делать нормальные связи сказать не возможно, поскольку описание мутное, а дженерик названия controller и manager вообще ничего не говорят.